# Finding the correct SharePoint solution to deploy to eliminate missing features

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wsp

So this is a bit of a vague question and I apologize but here goes nothing.

I am in the process of creating a SP2013 test farm that is an exact copy of our SP2010 production farm. When I mount the main content db for our main site collection I get a missing feature ID error. Here is the problem I need help with...

The solution that should have this feature is deployed to the farm already, however, as I was not working here when these solutions were made I don't know if I'm deploying the correct .wsp file. There are about 8 revisions so I naturally deployed the latest one.

So...
1. Would feature ID's change from version to version?
2. Is there a way to see which .wsp is deployed to my production farm.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Featuer ID will not change from version to version. you can see installed features from template/feature folder under SharePoint Hive (either 15 or 14 hive based on your sharepoint version).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay good to know that featureID won't change on different versions. I guess something else must be going on as to why the featureID is missing from the solution.

Comment: Did you do Pre upgrade check before migrating your farm, check this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219720.aspx, and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx for deprecated SharePoint features

Comment: Thanks for the info and yes I was aware of the site collection analyzer. The featureID I'm missing is from a custom solution. It sounds like I just need to figure out if there are multiple (different) versions of this solution that were built that might cause one version to have a feature that others don't. Wish the Dell consultants that did this before I worked here had left some documentation or used proper code deployment strategies.